# numpy: how to keep datatype of half precision array scalar input when adding a number

Tags: python, numpy

I have a half precision input that may be an array scalar `x = np.float32(3)`. I'd like to add one to it: `y = x + 1`. However `y` will be float64 instead of float32.

I can only think of two workarounds:

- convert the input to 1d array: `x = np.float32([3])` so that `y = x + 1` is float32
- convert 1 into lower precision: `y = np.float32(3) + np.float16(1)` is float32

However, I have a lot of functions, so the above fixes require me to add if-else statements to each function... Are there any better ways? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.add(..., dtype=np.float64)` like below:

```
>>> res = np.add(np.array([3], dtype=np.float32), np.float16(1), dtype=np.float64)
>>> res
array([4.])

>>> res.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Comment: I'm aiming for float32 output so it should be `np.add(np.float32(3), 1, dtype=np.float32)`

Comment: @Sam-gege, exactly, if you want `float32` you can write `dtype=np.float32`.

Answer (score 0):

As you note, adding a python value to a scalar array returns a value with the default dtype:

```
In [188]: np.float32(1.0) + 1
Out[188]: 2.0

In [189]: type(_)
Out[189]: numpy.float64
```

Why are concerned about this dtype?

If you add the scalar to an array, the dtype is preserved.

```
In [190]: np.array([1.0], 'float32')+1
Out[190]: array([2.], dtype=float32)
```

I'm suspicious of code that uses `np.float32(..)` instead of making an array.  Normally we worry about the dtype of large arrays, not individual terms - especially if the focus is on memory use.

The most natural case for getting a `np.float32` object is when we extract an element of an array:

```
In [193]: type(np.array([1.0], 'float32')[0])
Out[193]: numpy.float32
```

Type is preserved is both terms have the same type

```
In [196]: type(np.float32(12)+np.float32(34))
Out[196]: numpy.float32
```

It's the conversion of a scalar to numpy that creates the `float64`:

```
In [198]: np.array(1.0).dtype
Out[198]: dtype('float64')
```

Comment: I'm testing some machine learning algorithms using numpy, so I'd like them to be float32. In pytorch, `torch.tensor(2.) + 1` is float32. However, in numpy `np.array(2., dtype=np.float32) + 1` is float64. That's why I'm asking this question